# Клавиатура пианино, GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui, pyqt

Я пытаюсь реализовать клавиатуру пианино на *Python*. 
Порывшись в интернете, я не нашёл ничего стоящего, там или слишком намудрено или слишком примитивно, а мне нужна просто красивая клавиатура фортепиано, на которой каждая клавиша будет иметь отклик.

Решив делать всё самому без базы, я обратился к *Tkinter*. 
Я не желаю прописывать каждую клавишу и поэтому сгенерировал их циклом.

Появилась проблема: 
я не понимаю как сделать вид клавиатуры фортепиано, если я сдвину чёрные клавиши, то они будут просто чередоваться, не будет промежутка между *ми* и *фа*.

Конечная цель: сделать клавиатуру фортепиано на *Python* похожую на клавиатуру фортепиано.

**main.py**:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.geometry('900x500')
root.resizable(width = False, height = False)

def black_clicked(black_buttons):
    print(black_buttons)  

for black_buttons in range(6):
    btn = Button(text = f'{black_buttons}', bg = 'black', command=lambda black_buttons = black_buttons: black_clicked(black_buttons))
    btn.grid(column = black_buttons, row=0)

for white_buttons in range(8):
    btn = Button(text = f'{white_buttons}', bg ='white')
    btn.grid(column = white_buttons, row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ну например хранить в списке координаты кнопок, потом циклом по ним идти и размещать кнопки в нужных местах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вдруг вы решите обратиться к ***`PyQt`***, то как вариант, это может выглядеть примерно так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

BlackIdx = 1, 3, -1, 6, 8, 10
WhiteIdx = 0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11
KeyNames = 'C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#', 'A', 'A#', 'B'


class KeyButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    triggered = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, bool)
    
    def __init__(self, key, isBlack=False):
        super().__init__()
        self.key = key
        self.setProperty('isBlack', isBlack)

        octave, keyIdx = divmod(key, 12)
        self.setText('{}{}'.format(KeyNames[keyIdx], octave))

        self.setMinimumWidth(25)
        self.setMinimumSize(25, 80 if isBlack else 120)

        self.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred,
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding
        )
        self.pressed.connect(lambda: self.triggered.emit(key, True))
        self.released.connect(lambda: self.triggered.emit(key, False))


class Keyboard(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, octaves=2, octaveStart=3):
        super().__init__()
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.setRowStretch(0, 2)
        layout.setRowStretch(1, 1)
        layout.setSpacing(0)

        blackKeys = []
        for octave in range(octaves):
            for k in range(12):
                isBlack = k in BlackIdx
                keyButton = KeyButton(k + (octaveStart + octave) * 12, isBlack)
                keyButton.triggered.connect(self.keyTriggered)
                if isBlack:
                    keyPos = BlackIdx.index(k)
                    col = keyPos * 3 + 2
                    vSpan = 1
                    hSpan = 2
                    blackKeys.append(keyButton)
                else:
                    keyPos = WhiteIdx.index(k)
                    col = keyPos * 3
                    vSpan = 2
                    hSpan = 3
                col += octave * 21
                layout.addWidget(keyButton, 0, col, vSpan, hSpan)

            efSpacer = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            efSpacer.setMinimumWidth(25)
            layout.addWidget(efSpacer, 0, octave * 21 + 8, 1, 2)
            efSpacer.lower()
            baSpacer = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            baSpacer.setMinimumWidth(25)
            layout.addWidget(baSpacer, 0, octave * 21 + 20, 1, 2)
            baSpacer.lower()

        octave += 1
        lastButton = KeyButton((octaveStart + octave) * 12)
        lastButton.setMinimumWidth(32)
        lastButton.triggered.connect(self.keyTriggered)
        layout.addWidget(lastButton, 0, octave * 21, 2, 3)

        for keyButton in blackKeys:
            keyButton.raise_() 
        
        for col in range(layout.columnCount()):
            if col % 3 == 1:
                layout.setColumnStretch(col, 4)
            else:
                layout.setColumnStretch(col, 3)
        
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            KeyButton {
                border: 1px outset palette(dark);
                border-radius: 2px;
                background: white;
            }
            KeyButton:pressed {
                border-style: inset;
            }
            KeyButton[isBlack=true] {
                color: palette(light);
                background: black;
            }
            KeyButton[isBlack=true]:pressed {
                background: rgb(50, 50, 50);
            }
        ''')

    def keyTriggered(self, key, pressed):
        octave, keyIdx = divmod(key, 12)
        keyName = '{}{}'.format(KeyNames[keyIdx], octave)
        state = 'pressed' if pressed else 'released'
        print('Key {} ({}) {}'.format(key, keyName, state))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    keyboard = Keyboard()
    keyboard.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]